# Code to find a number is prime or not

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
public static bool IsPrime(int n)
  {
    if (n == 0 || n==1) { return false;}
    else
    {
      for (int i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
      {
        if(n/i == 0) {return false;}
        else {return true;}
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Replace `n / i` by `n % i`

Comment: Once you follow @PetervanderHeijden's advice, and you rethink your loop, the code should work. Then, there are several things to make your code better, but maybe that would be more suited to CodeReview

Comment: @oerkelens no, it wouldn't, it still returns after the first run of the loop..

Comment: @Stefan I edited my comment, just saw that flaw too :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really code review - but I am not sure it really fits CodeReview SE as it stands...

For starters, you don't need an `else` when your `if` clause cause a return.

Then, you want to check `n%i` instead of `n/i` of course.

Furthermore, your limit can be the square root of n instead of n/2 - just an optimisation.

Then you want to go through your loop until your limit before you return true.

Finally, you want to consider what you want to do with negative n. If you want that all negative n should return false, your first `if` simply becomes `if n < 2`. Otherwise, you have to add a clause for `n == -1`.

Putting all this together, (except for the square root optimisation), you would get:

```
public static bool IsPrime(int n)
{
  if (n < 2) return false;
  for (int i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
  {
    if(n%i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Why `i<=n/2`, and also why `i++`? Those are a little ineficient, especially `i++`

Comment: @Bakudan As I mentioned, you can use the square root of n as the upper limit, and of course, you can check /2 first, then go from 3 to upper limit with i+=2, but these are optimisations to the algorithm that go beyond getting the code cleaned up and working. If you really want top optimise this, you'd probably want to implement a sieve anyway.